# When writing tests, do I need to provide a file for file mainpulation functions?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing

I am new to testing and I want to test a function which will accept some data from a file and the split that data by each newline. This is in nodejs.

I have a separate function which will read the file and assign it to a variable. This is from a separate module so I am not testing this function specifically. My function takes the resulting data object and returns an array. The file itself comes from a service outside of my module, so I don't necessarily have access to it, the service needs to run to get that file. So I have a few general testing questions on how to write this test.

- When writing my test do I need to pass a file for it to split?
- If I need to give a file should I have a file in my tests directory to simulate the file in question?
- Right now my test calls the actual function which passes the data to the function I am writing the test for, is this the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When writing my test do I need to pass a file for it to split?

It sounds like you do, to achieve 100% automated testing.  Having small test files used in your automated tests should be pretty clean and still run pretty quickly.  Some would argue that these isn't pure unit testing / TDD because it performs IO, but I usually like it because tests using small files can still be extremely performant.

> If I need to give a file should I have a file in my tests directory to
>   simulate the file in question?

i think so, this is a clean solution.  I might even go as far as to put these tests in a separate integration test case.

> Right now my test calls the actual function which passes the data to
>   the function I am writing the test for, is this the wrong approach?

maybe, it's hard to tell without seeing your code.  Unittesting/TDD aims to keep tests only testing discrete units.  If this is calling an external service, it probably is "wrong"

It should be easy to test your "main" function.   If your main function takes a string or a stream as read by a file, performs some operation on it and returns an array, it should be extremely easy to isolate and test.

AFter that I think it would be valuable to test the function that loads/parses the file and returns its contents/stream works.  Which could use a test file in a test directory.  I think the no IO suggestion for unittest is primarily to keep speed quickly, so as long as it doesn't slow down your tests it is acceptable, (to me:)